# Ramsey Theory Similar Problem

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. We number the vertices of $K_{mn+1}$ $1,2,...,mn+1$ and color each of its edges either blue or red. Prove that at least one of the following must occur:

$a.$ There exist $m+1$ vertices, the edges between them are all blue. (A complete $K_{m+1}$ blue subgraph)

$b.$There exist $n+1$ vertices numbered $v_1<v_2<...<v_{n+1}$ for which $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}$ is colored red for $i=1,...,n$

This looks like Erdos Szekeres relating to posets but I can't find the right operation. This also looks like it has something to do with Ramsey theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(k)$ be the length of the longest subsequence $a_1<a_2<\dots <a_l=k$ such that edges between consecutive vertices are red.

Clearly if $f(k)=f(l)$ then the edge between $k$ and $l$ must be blue. Suppose that $f(k)\in\{1,2,\dots n\}$ for all $k$, then by the pigeonhole principle there must be at least $m+1$ integers that share the same value of $f$. These $m+1$ integers form a blue $K_{m+1}$.

Comment: My edit was to change $f(n)\in ....$ to $f(k)\in ....$ and to take the "d" out of "pidgeon. ".  English spelling is broken and needs repair.  Very nice succinct answer.